# Show/hide div in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm pretty fresh to JS.

For n amount of bar divs I have n amount foo divs. By clicking on bar[1], I want foo[1] to show or hide. The same goes for bar[2]/foo[2], bar[5]/foo[5], bar[3]/foo[3],...bar[n]/foo[n] in no exact order.

With this code I am able to show and hide, but only all of the divs at the same time. What should I change, so that I am able to hide or show only one of the divs?

```js
function getContent() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].style.display === "none") {
      x[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

document.querySelector(".bar").addEventListener("click", getContent);
```

```css
.foo {
  display: none;
}

.bar {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```
<div>
     <div class="bar" onclick="getContent()">bar</div>
</div>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
```

Comment: Please edit the snippet to show your html.

Comment: that actually does change them one at a time, just does it really fast. look into setTimeout to stage them out. I would actually do it all in CSS though, then just set a className on <body> to trigger different "states" in CSS.

Comment: Don't use both `onclick` and `addEventListener`. The function will run twice.

Comment: You need to introduce a variable that stores the currently visible div (as in, the index of it in the range of 0 to x.length-1). When the click is handled, you increment the variable, then iterate over the divs and check `i` against it. Also, if you want to do this using classes, you need to use .classList.add() and .classList.remove(). However you will need separate classes for selecting and hiding the divs.

Comment: *What should I change, so that I am able to hide or show only one of the divs?* Which one, then?

Comment: Also an option: the `<details>` element, which does this for you without _any_ JS at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use JS here, HTML is more powerful than you think: if you want to show-or-hide information, [the <details> element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)'s got you covered.

```css
.all-or-nothing summary {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<details class="all-or-nothing">
  <summary>Toggle all divs</summary>
  <div>
    The first div
  </div>
  <div>
    The second div
  </div>
    <div>
    The third div
  </div>
</details>
```

Comment: One more question, is it possible to somehow change the triangle within the summary tag?

Comment: Absolutely: in this post I used `display:inline-block` for that very reason, but if  you combine that with `... summary:before { content: " ..... "; ... }` you have all the freedom to customize what folks see instead of a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to hold the index of the current DIV to show, rather than looping over all the DIVs.

```js
let fooIndex = 0;
let allFoo = document.querySelectorAll(".foo");

function getContent() {
  if (fooIndex < allFoo.length) {
    allFoo[fooIndex].classList.toggle("foo");
    allFoo[fooIndex].classList.toggle("bar");
    fooIndex++;
  }
}

document.querySelector(".bar").addEventListener("click", getContent);
```

```css
.foo {
  display: none;
}

.bar {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="bar">bar</div>
</div>
<div class="foo">foo1</div>
<div class="foo">foo2</div>
<div class="foo">foo3</div>
<div class="foo">foo4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//let fooIndex = 0;

function getContent() {
    var x = $(".card");
    x.append('<div class="foo" onclick="hideContent(this)">foo1</div>');
    //$(this).addClass('bar');
  }

   function hideContent(a) {
    $(a).removeClass('foo');
    $(a).addClass('bar');
  }
```

```css
.foo {
  display: none;
}

.bar {
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div onclick="getContent();" class="bar">bar</div>
</div>
```